# How to dynamical bind a method reference to a trait?

Tags: scala, traits, method-reference

Given

```
def add(x: Int, y: Int): Int = x + y

val addAsMethodReference: (Int, Int) => Int = add _

trait BinaryOperator {
  def execute(x: Int, y: Int): Int
}

val addAsBinaryOperator: BinaryOperator = addAsMethodReference...?
```

How do I bind `addAsMethodReference` to `BinaryOperator` **without implementing `BinaryOperator` by hand**?

Java 8 SAM will just work.  I could use the method reference anywhere binary operator trait is used in Java 8.

Ideally, I want to write something like:

```
var addAsBinaryOperator: BinaryOperator = addAsMethodReference.asNewInstanceOf[BinaryOperator]
```

The reason I want this `asNewInstanceOf` method is it would work for any method signature.  I don't care how many parameters are being passed.  If I had to implement this by hand I have to carefully match each `x` and `y`.  This is error prone at a larger scale.

The specification of `left.asNewInstanceOf[right]` would be if the `right` side has more than one abstract method, it fails at compilation.  If the `left` side is not a functional type that matches the single abstract method signature in the `right` side, it would fail at compilation.  The `right` side doesn't need to be a trait, it could be an abstract class with a single abstract method.

Comment: Could you post some code of what you would like to be able to write exactly?

Comment: Mmm.....then I think that you want magic.

Comment: That's okay to say this is impossible in Scala.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you could make the implicit conversion

```
implicit def myConversion(f: (Int, Int) ⇒ Int): BinaryOperator = new BinaryOperator {
    def execute(x: Int, y: Int): Int = f(x, y)
  }
```

and if it's in scope, you can just do

```
val addAsBinaryOperator: BinaryOperator = addAsMethodReference
```

for any binary function of integers returning an integer. Although maybe this also classifies as "implementing by hand". I can't see a way in which the compiler magically realizes that you want to interpret a function as an instance of a user-created trait with some particular structure.

Comment: This is closer than the other answer.  But you are still manually using the variables x and y.

Comment: I'm not sure how you expect the method to know that it's supposed to bind to `execute` without you telling it.  This is as good as it gets... well, at least until version 2.13, when the `mind-reading` library becomes available.

Comment: @Pyrolistical The only alternative to this I can think about, is making some macros. Nonetheless, that's already farther than I would go for such feature. As @dhg mentioned, until `mind-reading` is not released, you won't get the compiler do such things. Maybe you can make those traits that you want to assign methods to, more flexible or more controlled, in such a way that you can provide that functionality.

Comment: This is done and dusted in Java 8 with single abstract methods.  If you can't do this in Scala, so be it.

Answer (score 0):

NEW ANSWER:

This does what you want.  It dynamically creates a `BinaryOperator` object whose `execute` method is bound to `addAsMethodReference`:

```
def add(x: Int, y: Int): Int = x + y

val addAsMethodReference: (Int, Int) => Int = add _

trait BinaryOperator {
  def execute(x: Int, y: Int): Int
}

val addAsBinaryOperator: BinaryOperator = 
    new BinaryOperator{ def execute(x: Int, y: Int): Int = addAsMethodReference(x,y) }
```

OLD ANSWER

Is this what you want?

```
implicit class EnhancedBinaryOperator(val self: BinaryOperator) extends AnyVal {
  def addAsMethodReference(a: Int, b: Int) = a + b
}

val o: BinaryOperator = ???    // anything here
o.addAsMethodReference(1,2)    // addAsMethodReference is now on BinaryOperator
```

Comment: this is just a weird way of implementing it by hand

Comment: well what the heck are you asking for then?  maybe you can give some code for how you expect it to be used??

Comment: @Pyrolistical This is the usual pattern to add methods to classes/traits/objects that you don't have access to (like from the standard language library).

Comment: No, that is what I mean by "implementing by hand".  I literally want to assign a functional type to a trait and have an instance of that trait without messing about with all the parameters.